# Stacked column not lining up with highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts to plot to series of data. However, I'm having a problem lining up the series on top of each other as the columns are very slightly misaligned. My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="highcharts.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // global vars
        col1 = '#7B7B7B';                   
        col2 = '#FFFFFF';   

        // Set chart options
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            chart: { defaultSeriesType: 'column', backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0)" },
            plotOptions: { column:{ stacking: 'normal' }},                
            title: { text: ''},
            legend: {enabled: false}                
            });

        // Initialize charts
        function createCharts(){
            chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {    renderTo: 'chart-1' },
                xAxis: {    categories: ['now.', 'then.']   },
                yAxis: {    title: {style: {color: '#FFFFFF'},
                            text: '[Total Amount]'          },                  
                                min: 0  },
                series: [{name: 'Measure_A',      data: [0, 0], pointWidth: 28}, 
                         {name: 'Measure_B', data: [0, 0], pointWidth: 28}]
                });
                }

       // update charts 
        function updateCharts(){

            old_A =  chart1.series[0].data[0].y;
            old_B =  chart1.series[1].data[0].y;

            A = Math.random() * 10;
            B = Math.random() * 10;

            chart1.series[0].setData([{color: col1, name: 'Measure_A',   y: A,     pointWidth: 28},
                          {color: col2, name: 'Measure_A',   y: old_A, pointWidth: 28}]);
            chart1.series[1].setData([{color: col1, name: 'Measure_B',   y: B,     pointWidth: 28}, 
                          {color: col2, name: 'Measure_B',   y: old_B, pointWidth: 28}]);}               



    </script>               
<body onload="createCharts();">         
    <div id="chart-1" style="width:250px; height:150px"></div>
    <button type="button" id="button-1" onclick="updateCharts()">Update chart</button>      
</body>
</html>
```

To illustrate the problem I am adding a series of data to the chart each time the button is pressed, and the current data is on the left hand side. I want to use the same color for each column, and just to demarcate the spaces in the bar using a line. But, the column stacks appear to be very slightly misaligned and I'm not sure why.

[image]

**EDIT:** I've included a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Q68pC/3/) to a fiddle, but strangely this problem does not exist here.

Comment: Can you point us to a working fiddle by any chance?

Comment: @malonso I just added one - but can't recreate the problem!

Comment: @celenius is this happening in all browsers?

Comment: @Nobita It's happening on Firefox, Safari and Chrome. It appears to be just a linethickness off, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @celenius Can't tell you how many times I've been there.  Unfortunately, in each case it was something I was doing wrong. I just ended up needing to strip everything out piece by piece until I figured out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If the borders are giving issues, you might want to try using a 1px height background image to show the seperation between the bars. I know it's not the ideal situation but eventually it might solve the issue after all.